# Dell Latitude E6420 8GB memory showing as 3GB Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, dell-latitude

This is what RAMMON is showing;
Ram Type    DDR3    Not Populated
Maximum Clock Speed (MHz)   666.67 (JEDEC)
Maximum Transfer Speed (MHz)    DDR3-1333
Maximum Bandwidth (MB/s)    PC3-42600
Memory Capacity (MB)    8192

This is what I see in Windows 7 task manager;
physical memory (mb)
total 3241
cached 433
available 498
Free 77

system information;
installed memory 4gb (3.17gb usable)

32 bit operating system.

Is this normal? what's going on? Thanks.

Edit: thanks for the reponses.
I am more asking about why is it only 3gb usable that I am seeing not the max 4gb for a 32bit OS?
And see that it was answered by the first comments, thanks

Comment: what's the point of plugging so much RAM on a 32-bit system?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 32 bit can only "see" up to 3 or 3 dot "something" GB or RAM.

32 bit can only refer up to 4 GB (`2^32`) but some part of it must be used for other things like video and other hardware so you end up with around 3GB.

Only way to use more than that is by upgrading to **64 bit**.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)

> Physical Memory Limits: Windows 7
>
> The following table specifies the limits on physical memory for
>   Windows 7.
>
> [image]

So 32 bit Windows is limited to 4 GB. 64 bit Windows can use more.

In addition, from [The usable memory may be less than the installed memory on Windows 7-based computers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610):

> On a computer that is running Windows 7, the usable memory (RAM) may
>   be less than the installed memory.
>
> For example, a 32-bit version of Windows 7 may report that there is
>   only 3.5 GB of usable system memory on a computer that has 4 GB of
>   memory installed.
>
> Or, a 64-bit version of Windows 7 may report that there is only 7.1 GB
>   of usable system memory on a computer that has 8 GB of memory
>   installed.

...

> The reduction in available system memory depends on the configuration
>   of the following:
>
> - The devices that are installed in the computer and the memory that is reserved by those devices
> - The ability of the motherboard to handle memory
> - The System BIOS version and settings
> - The version of Windows 7 that is installed (For example, Windows 7 Starter Edition only supports 2 GB of installed memory.)
> - Other system settings

Answer (score 0):

As nutty says the 32 bit model is a bit limited, you can how ever make sure you got the PAE installed, it means Physical Address Extension, and it works rougly like if you have a power strip and you connect another powerstrip in to that one, you loose one outlet but get 4 new. Except this is with memory so you use some of the memory to tell where the rest of the memory is.

This is ofcause supported by windows 7.

Ofcause source for credibility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366796(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a matter of size. With 32 bits the system should handle 2^32 bits (4GB), but Windows doesn't go to the edge.

Updating to a 64 bits version could make you handle the full 4GB.